# My sails.js hook is not initializing when installed as a node module

Tags: sails.js

I created a new sails.js hook (using `sails-generate-hook`), but when I attempt to install it as an npm module it doesn't initialize.

I copied the code directly from the `index.js` in the `hooks` sub-folder the generator created, but still I can't get it to fire the `initialize()` method.

I installed `sails-hook-dev` and it is working correctly, so I'm assuming there's something I'm missing in my newly created hook, when it is installed as a module instead of in the `hooks` folder.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer to my question.

By reading the `sails-hook-dev` code it looks like you have to "tell" sails that your npm module is a hook by adding an `isHook` indicator into your `package.json` file.

```
  // package.json
  "sails": {
    "isHook": true
  }
```

After I added that into my `package.json` file, my module seems to work the same as when it's in the `hooks` folder.

EDIT: Thanks to @sgress454 for pointing me to the [documentation for installable hooks](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks/installablehooks.html) (hooks as an npm module).

Comment: Documentation for installable hooks [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks/installablehooks.html).

Comment: thanks @sgress454 I'll edit my answer to add a link to the documentation. Not sure how I missed the docs on hooks before. They're very complete.